# Formatting email body in s-nail command bash

Tags: bash, shell, email, unix

I am using `s-nail` command in my script to send emails. It is doing its job well and good. But I want to format the email body.

Currently, my mail body looks like below:

```
Hi Team,
Below jobs completed successfully:
job1 job2 job3 job4
```

It would look good if it is like below:

```
Hi Team,
Below jobs completed successfully:
job1
job2
job3
job4
```

My code looks like below:

```
email_body="Hi Team,
Below jobs completed successfully:
${jobs[*]}"

email_subject="job details"

email_to="xxxxxxxx.com"

echo -e "${email_body}" | s-nail -S smtp-use-starttls -S ssl-verify=ignore -S smtp-auth=login -S smtp="<smtp_server>:<smtp_port>" -S smtp-auth-user="<smtp_user>" -S smtp-auth-password="<smtp_password>" -r <from_address> -s "${email_subject}" -. "${email_to}"
```

I want my array elements to be printed line by line in the mail body.

Could someone please help me here..!

Regards,
Rohith

Comment: How is jobs defined / populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to probably split the `jobs` variable into individual words and iterate over them either via a function or via in-line code since I'm not sure how `$jobs` is populated e.g:

```
jobs="job1 job2 job3"

split(){
for job in $jobs
do
    echo $job
done
}

email_body="Hi Team,
Below jobs completed successfully:
$(split)
"

echo "$email_body"
```

or

```
jobs="job1 job2 job3"

email_body="Hi Team,
Below jobs completed successfully:
$(for job in $jobs
do
    echo $job
done)"

echo "$email_body"
```

Both output:

```
Hi Team,
Below jobs completed successfully:
job1
job2
job3
```